# VBA - MS Access 2016 - saving a CSV from a form and adding a value from the form to the file name

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-csv

I am working with a form in Ms Access 2016, and using VBA, I need to add to the VBA, to export a csv file with the forms values, and also add a few more columns into the CSV from the table the form is derived from, (all from the same table) there is only one table associated with the form, “tblOnlineJobTable”, and when the button named “cmdAction” is clicked on the form it generates a unique despatch group code, and adds it to the  “tblOnlineJobTable”, I need to add the depatchgroup code value, the field is named “txtDespatchGroupBatchNumber” to the exported csv file name.

I have heard that is would be simpler to convert the form to a report first, before saving as a CSV, which all needs to be achieved when clicking  “cmdAction”.

I have not shown what I have tried as none of it has worked and will probably just confuse matters.

I am struggling changing the VBA to achieve the above, the currect VBA in place is:

```
    Private Sub cmdAction_Click()

        If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    
     If Valid Then
    
        If Nz(Me.txtDespatchGroupBatchNumber, "") <> "" Then
            If vbNo = MsgBox("Warning - You have already sent this - this will create a new DGN number, " & _
                    " Do you wish to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Warning") Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    
        ' 01Aug17 - add the nz to get started
        ' 07aug17 - change the DGN to a text field
'        Me.txtDespatchGroupBatchNumber = Nz(DMax("DespatchGroupBatchNumber", "tblOnlineJobTable"), 0) + 1
        Me.txtDespatchGroupBatchNumber = "W" & Nz(DMax("DGNnumber", "qryfrmDespatchEntry_maxDGN"), 0) + 1

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_wtbl_DespatchEntry_update"
        
        ' 01Aug17
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_wtbl_DespatchEntry_update_wtbl"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        
        MsgBox "Jobs have been Updated", vbInformation, "Information"
        
    ' 01aug17 - always enabled
    '        Me.cmdPrintDelivery.Enabled = True
        Me.cmdPrintDelivery.SetFocus
        Me.cmdAction.Enabled = False
        
    '''        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not seeing any export code in that procedure. Apparently code is supposed to update table. Does this all work? Now edit question to show attempted code that does not work and describe what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Are you using TransferText command?

Comment: Thank you. There is no code added yet to export the csv, and the existing code does work. I need to find the code to export as a csv and also add the value in txtDespatchGroupBatchNumber field to the file name. I have just experimented with changing this to a report so I can investigate saving but receiving the error "compile error, block if without endif" using the following code:

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow and trying to work out how to add the VBA as it states there are too many characters, highly embarrasing.

Comment: If posted code is not working, what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Question should focus on one issue. Get this code working then have another question about exporting to CSV.